# How do I open a Open File dialog in OS X using C++?

Tags: c++, user-interface, macos

I'm working on an application using OpenGL and C++ that parses some structured input from a file and displays it graphically. I'd like to start an Open File dialog when the application loads to allow the user to choose the file they want to have displayed. I haven't been able to find what I need on the web. Is there a way to achieve this in C++? If so, how? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which framework are you using to show an OpenGL window? The answer will depend on that. Are you using GLUT? Or what?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am indeed using GLUT, but I'm a little worried that it matters what I'm using. Under Windows there is an Windows API call for handling file browsing. In the code it's just a function that returns the path to the file the user selected (but the dialog is handled by the OS). I was hoping to find something similar for OS X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two choices, a quick one, and a good one:

- Quick and pretty simple, use the [Navigation Services](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ProvidingNavigationDialogs/nsx_tasks/nsx_tasks.html) framework from Carbon and `NavCreateGetFileDialog()`. You'll be done quick, and you'll have to learn almost nothing new, but your code won't run in 64-bit (which Apple is pushing everyone towards) and you'll have to link the Carbon framework. Navigation Services is [officially removed](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/Carbon64BitGuide/HIToolboxChanges/HIToolboxChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004381-CH4-SW5) in 64-bit, and is generally deprecated going forward (though I expect it to linger in 32-bit for quite a while).
- A little more work the first time you do it (because you need to learn some Objective-C), but much more powerful and fully supported, wrap up [NSOpenPanel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsopenpanel/) in an Objective-C++ class and expose that to your C++. This is my [Wrapping C++](http://robnapier.net/blog/wrapping-c-take-2-1-486) pattern, just backwards. If you go this way and have trouble, drop a note and I'll try to speed up posting a blog entry on it.

Comment: Both links in the second point are broken

Answer (score 3):

To add to what Rob wrote:

Unfortunately, there's no simple equivalent to Windows's `GetOpenFileName`.

1. If you use Carbon:  I don't really think `NavCreatGetFileDialog` is easy to use... you can use [this code](http://www.carbondev.com/site/?page=NavCreateGetFileDialog) in the CarbonDev to see how to use it. The code there returns `CFURLRef`. To get the POSIX path, use [CFURLGetFileSystemReprestnation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/corefoundation/reference/CFURLRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001206-CH1g-F12860).
2. That said, I recommend you to use Cocoa. Rob will write a blog post how to use `NSOpenPanel` from GLUT :)

Comment: hahahaha.... Actually, poking around a little more, Apple has provided some nice sample code for GLUT. Most useful for this problem is GLUTWindow, since it gives you the handle you the objects you'll need to run a sheet. Apple also has a least one Technote on using GLUT; it's worth searching their site for more stuff. http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/glut

Comment: It should be a comment to Rob's answer

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to open file dialog on macOS is to use [AppKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit) framework, which a part of [Cocoa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_(API)#Main_frameworks) API.

You will need the class [NSOpenPanel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsopenpanel) from AppKit, and create appropriate Objective-C++ wrapping around to use it from an ordinary C++ code. It is not an easy task for a person without much macOS development experience. Fortunately, it is not necessary nowadays, since existing wrappers already can be found in GitHub. Please take a look, for example, at

- [Native File Dialog](https://github.com/mlabbe/nativefiledialog), or
- [Native File Dialog Extended](https://github.com/btzy/nativefiledialog-extended)